# Validating Neural Network

Tags: neural-networks, matrix, computational-statistics

I have a relatively large set of labelled data which I am using to verify how well-trained a neural-network I wrote is. The network uses a competitive learning technique. It has N output neurons, each time a sample is fed into it this is labelled as belonging to the class corresponding to the network that returned the highest output.

The end-result of my verification is an NxM matrix A. Each row in A is an output neuron and each column is a class.

For example, say:

```
A =
[ 1 2 3 ]
[ 7 0 9 ]
[ 3 4 7 ]
```

This translates to:

1 sample belonging to class 1, 2 samples belonging to class 2, 3 samples belonging to class 3 have been classified as belonging to cluster 1. (Output neuron 1 returned the highest value)

7 samples belonging to class 1, 0 samples belonging to class 2, 3 samples belonging to class 3 have been classified as belonging to cluster 2.

etc.

Now, as my network's learning strategy improves (I am testing different learning algorithm), I expect the heterogeneity of the rows to decrease. That is, each output neuron should predominantly fire at one class of inputs, so moving to something like

```
A =
[ 0 0 5 ]
[ 14 0 0]
[ 0 14 0]
```

(Perhaps not this well-defined, but I hope you get the idea.)

My question is: Is there any way to formally prove this? I.e.: given two matrices A and A', is there a way to show that rows tend to converge to including mostly samples from one class?

Comment: Just trying to understand the question: when you want to *show that rows tend to converge*, do you mean that given a sequence of matrices $A_1$, $A_2$, ..., you want to quantify whether they are getting closer to the "ideal" matrix $A'$? That is, you want to make inference based on an empirical sequence of matrices?

Comment: @RichardHardy, essentially, ideally a matrix A should have each row with all values set to 0 except for 1. That is because each neuron should only recognize values belonging to one class. As my network's learning ability improve, matrices should get progressively closer to such 'ideal'. So yes, I would be comparing a sequence of matrices and showing that, as I implement more advanced algorithms, they get close to the ideal matrix. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks, I think it does. Interesting question, I will think about it.

Comment: you can compute the entropy for each row to measure how certain the neuron outputs are and perhaps plot the entropy over time (averaged across rows)